# Rich links in hangouts chat

Tags: google-hangouts

I'm working on the sharing aspects of a website, and got stuck with google's hangouts chat.

I want links to the site to be displayed as "cards" with my preview image (ideally, an animated gif), the same way these are:

- https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python
- https://xkcd.com/387/
- https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC2hxYQtGLEkcOMK4h8JRycA

I was hoping the generic "og:image" meta tag would do the trick, but that's not working
So, I checked out the source code of these pages, but that didn't help either:

In the github page, for example, the url to the image can be found in the og:image and twitter:image:src meta tags. I thought it would be weird for 'twitter:image:src' to be the solution, but I tried anyways. It didn't work.

I've been looking everywhere for some documentation on this, but all I can find is stuff about creating a bot, which is not what I'm looking for.

Thanks for any advice

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please read the entire page, not just the first paragraph or two, especially the section with the numbered list of items.

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks for that page, I didn't know about it. However, I do not see which rule I am violating: I have described a clear, solvable and reproducible problem; I have detailed the steps I took to resolve it before coming to SO; I am not asking for a book / tool / etc recommendation; My question is not about hardware or server infrastructure.

Comment: The one that you just removed with your edit 2 minutes ago, where you asked *Can't find documentation on rich links*, where you were asking for a link to the documentation. :-) Specifically, it's item #4 in the numbered list on that page related to off-site resources.

Comment: I agree the title was not describing the problem well, which is why I updated it, but I still don't agree with your main point: I am not asking about book or tool recommendations. Just trying to convey that I am not necessarily looking for a ready-made solution.

Comment: Didn't say *book or tool*. I said *off-site resource*, which is what your original question appeared to be asking for (a link to documentation).